# Is user a callback function and how does it work?

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, I am not understanding what user is. onAuthStateChangedListener calls onAuthStateChanged(auth, user), it is a listener that is always listening.  It is supposed to be a callback, but there is no user function defined anywhere.  I have listened to the description over and over.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
      if (user) {
        createUserDocumentFromAuth(user);
      }
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is this onAuthStateChangedListener from firebase? if so it's better to mention it, otherwise please provide that function body too.

Comment: Yes, it is firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, `user` is not callback but a parameter of callback.
It will be helpful if we rewrite the code as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const authStateHandler = (user) => {
      if (user) {
        createUserDocumentFromAuth(user);
      }
      setCurrentUser(user);
    }
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener(authStateHandler);

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: What type of value does user have, it seems like it was never declared?